# TVML files in xcode?

Tags: xcode, tvos, tvml

I am building a TVOS app in Xcode. I know it is recommended to have following file structure:

- `client/`  (this folder is outside my project folder)
- `client/templates`  (tvml files)
- `client/js`  (javascript files)

But `client/` is not part of my `tvosapp.xcodeproj`, therefore in XCode, I cannot see the tVML files.

Questions:

1. How do I include the `/templates` `/js` folders in my project to be submitted in XCode?
2. If I have 2 projects, how can I separate the `/templates` `/js` folder for each project if I share the same `/client` folder?

Comment: You can put all in the same folder as long as you llink the files correctly in your code.

Comment: My answer here might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404995/can-you-host-tvjs-files-on-the-apple-tv-instead-of-an-external-server/33405700#33405700

Answer (score 1):

Check out this https://github.com/toshi0383/TVMLKitchen its something I came across a couple days ago and it works great. It requires a bit of restructure to your current TVOS app as it hijacks the Navigation and focus engine (pretty sure at least). I branched what I was working on and used this and my life is so much easier. No server, all parsed on the client. Extremely fast and a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need not have the exact same specified structure of `client` from the sample code, to me, as a front-end developer it looks bloated.

Have a look at this [sample code](https://github.com/emadalam/tvml-catalog-using-atvjs) that I ported from the original sample code which is using a better structured client setup. Though it uses [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework, you'll get a sense of how to better structure your client application.